# Google Maps API Customized Legend

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to figure out how to add a custom legend based on my earthquake data map with circles that display magnitude. I've been able to add the Legend box if you will but can't seem to figure out how to add the magnitude variable explanation.

Here is my code so far.

```
<head>
  <title>Sample Map</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }

    #info-box {
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid black;        
      padding: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 45%;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #legend {
      background: white;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-left: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #title {
      background: white;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-top: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }  

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="info-box">Earthquake Data</div>
  <div id="legend">Legend</div>
  <div id="title">USGS 4.5+ Magnitude Earthquake Data in the Last 30 days </div>
  <script>

    var map;
      function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
      zoom: 2    
      });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 47.2448, lng: -122.4378},
      map: map,
      title: 'Global View'
      });

    map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
      var magnitude = feature.getProperty('mag');
      return {
      icon: getCircle(magnitude)
      };
    });

    function getCircle(magnitude) {
      var circle = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillColor: 'purple',
            fillOpacity: .2,
        scale: Math.pow(2, magnitude) / 2,
        strokeColor: 'yellow',
        strokeWeight: .5
      };
      return circle;
    }

    map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
        document.getElementById('info-box').textContent =
            event.feature.getProperty("title");
      });

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(
      document.getElementById('legend'));

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(
      document.getElementById('title'));

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT].push(
      document.getElementById('info-box'));

    map.data.loadGeoJson('4.5plusmeq.json');
    }

  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap"
      async defer></script>
</body>
```

link to the map as displayed currently:
http://students.washington.edu/sbuffor/samplemap.html

Comment: Where is the data that you're pulling? ie `event.feature.getProperty('title');`. Seems you should be able to update the element id of `legend` with the same `click` function you're updating the `title` element with, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to load into the `legend` box but maybe this helps?

It seems you're looking to update the `legend` with data relative to the `event` the user clicks. You should be able to do this inside your existing `listener` like:

```
document.getElementById('legend').textContent = 'Mag Type: ' + event.feature.getProperty('magType');
```

Hopefully this is helpful but it might be completely off from what you're looking to do!

[image: snippet]

**UPDATE:**

Yes, the legend you provided is an image. If you're open to using images, simply include the image in the legend div like:

```
<div id="map">
    <img src="http://www.bencomeau.com/img/legend.png" alt="Legend">
</div>
```

And you'll want to remove the `background` and `border/border-radius` properties of the `legend` from your CSS as well so it looks appropriate.

I've done this via JavaScript to produce this look:

[image: updatedSnippet]

Comment: Ok that is really cool how you did that. Not quite what I'm looking for I'll be honest. I think I can work with that if I can get a static "Legend" box to stay there while when the user clicks the magnitude shows as a # like it is with this new setup. I can change the lower info window to just place. Also what I'm really trying to do is show a representative circle very similar to the ones on the map (maybe smaller) to be on the legend in a way that shows that a larger circle is larger magnitude and smaller circles are smaller magnitude. I'm learning a lot with your help, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be easier to possibly make a .jpg image with gimp and post it on the map to show the changes in magnitude? I'd really prefer to learn how to code it. `map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
   document.getElementById('legend').textContent = 'Magnitude:' + event.feature.getProperty('mag');
   });`

Comment: This is the piece that I think I need but I can't figure how how to apply it in my map to work with the variables of magnitude and location        `var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
for (var style in styles) {
  var name = style.name;
  var icon = style.icon;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + icon + '"> ' + name;
  legend.appendChild(div);
}` got this info from [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/adding-a-legend)

Comment: Should the content be fixed or variable? It seems you're saying it would need to change for the respective click but earlier it seems it could be static (ie: 7 circles from small to large with it showing that smaller circles are less mag, larger are larger mag). Show me an example of the data that should be inside the legend.

Comment: look at the legend in step 2. I think I figured out this was a image file that was created and not necessarily a coded legend using javascript. [http://students.washington.edu/ksymer/tgis503lab3.php] I would want more of the magnitude side of the legend. I tried watching several tutorials on youtube regarding google maps api and just more general javascript in hopes of understanding more of what I should do, but it didn't really help me in this project. I am satisfied with the way the map is currently, but if I can learn some additional things I am down with that.

Comment: See updated answer for a way to handle it. It can be done in pure javascript without images but using an image is an acceptable route too. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am forever in your debt bud. Thanks for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Glad it helps. Don't forget to mark as the solution for future views if it fits what you need. Cheers!